# default Installation directory whonix?

Tags: python, installation, directory

But I can't seem to find the standard installation directory within whonix, I've installed with sudo apt-get .. install a python program which installed "name.py" in "/path/tofile"

And I'd really like to excecute the file, but I can't find it anywhere,
Not in dolphin manually, 
not by searching in dolphin
not by entering the filename in the specified search protocol of whoninx with settings to search in:

```
"file///"
"/"
"/home"
"/bin"
"/usr"
```

Could anyone tell me where the default installation folder is located within whonix?

*analog to eg: C:/program files for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `sudo apt-get install <package name>` it copies files to many locations, there isn't really a "default installation folder"- it depends on the package.

To display a list of files a package contains do `dpkg -L <package name>`.
For example, this could bring back a list of files in `/usr/share` which will be supporting files for the application (shared files, manuals, documentaiton, examples). And maybe a binary executable in `/usr/bin` which is used to run the program.

If you're having trouble locating a specific file, you could try searching the file system:
`sudo find / -name whatever.py`

Comment: Thank you, I did not comprehend that clearly, now I do. That last command I find especially helpfull, thanks to that I found the file.